# How to count lines from multiple files and redirect it to a file?

Tags: shell, unix

How to count lines of files from multiple projects, with multiple extensions and put this information into a file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `bash` you can simply:

```
shopt -s extglob       #best in your ~/.profile
wc -l {Project,OtherProject}/**/*.{cpp,h} > LineCounter.txt
```

the `**` will expand recursively. Limitation: for the large trees could end with "Arg count too long" error message.

or case insensitive

```
shopt -s extglob nocaseglob
wc -l {Project,OtherProject}/**/*.{cpp,h} > LineCounter.txt
```

also, sometimes is missing the `\n` from the last line of the file. In such cases, the `wc` reports by 1 less lines. You can use the `grep` for counting (a bit slower as `wc`), like:

```
grep -c '' files...
```

counts the number of lines

```
grep -c '.' files...
```

counts the number of non-empty lines, what contains at least one character (space too)

```
grep -c '[^ ]' files...
```

counts the really not empty lines, e.g. only lines what contains some non-space character, and so on...

Answer (score 2):

```
find Project1 Project2 -type f \( -iname \*.cpp -o -iname \*.h \) -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l > LineCounter.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Do you really want mess up the output file with the error messages, e.g.: `2>&1`? +1 anyway. :)